# How to Edit Tokens in a String?

Tags: java, string, token, text-processing

I want to edit a list of uniform data in a text file, here is a sample of the data:

[image: Input File]

I want to format the data so it looks like this:

[image: Output File]

So far, I have been able to read each line and token scanner by scanner but I'm not sure how to edit each token so that

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Data { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("PortlandWeather2014.txt"));

    int lineNumber = 1;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        Scanner token = new Scanner(line); 
        while(token.hasNext()){
            if (token.hasNext()) {
                String tokenS = token.next();
        }

        lineNumber++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to store each token in "tokenS" and edit it the corresponding format in the second imgur link by using an if statement to determine whether "tokenS" is a string or double, but I am not really sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

consider

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();

    String tokens [] = line.split (" ");  // space or tab?
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
    while (String tok : tokens) {
      sb.append (tok).append ("\t");  // maybe tok needs formatting
      // can test if tok is double maybe by using 
      // Double#parseDouble(java.lang.String)
    }

    // now print sb
    System.out.println (sb);

    }
}
```